# Image carousel with nativescript- Angular 2

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I need to implement an image carousel with nativescript-angular2. I looked into most of the plugins, they don't seem to work for me. What is the best way to implement an image carousel? 
I need to implement something like this on my app.

```
 <StackLayout> 
    .......Image Carousel....... 
      <GridLayout>
          <Button>
          <Button>
          <Button>
          <Button>
      </GridLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to have images that are scrollable you can use the **RadListView** from the nativescript-telerik-ui plugin. That component is free and provides multiple features for showing "items" with custom template in all orientations, in different layouts (stack, grid with columns etc.), it has load on demand, pull to refresh and so on.

[Here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/ListView/overview) is the official documentation of that component, also you can find many sdk examples [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular).

Answer (score 0):

here are some examples of what i think you are looking for

https://bradmartin.net/2016/05/31/create-horizontal-scrolling-lists-in-nativescript-apps/

http://www.nativescriptsnacks.com/snippets/2016/05/30/horizontal-scroller.html

Comment: Good solutions if you don't have a bunch of items (10+) or large image files. If you have many images/items use a listview or android will crash and burn :) not sure that is addressed in the links above